# passwordless root login from aws ec2 to ec2

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to start a vertica cluster on 3 ec2 instances(node1, node2, node3) which requires root login via ssh between the instances.

On node1, the main node...as a root user, I generated keys using `ssh-keygen`

On node2 and node3, I edited the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file with this:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no`
```

then added the id_rsa.pub key to node2 and node3 in both `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

then did a

```
service sshd restart
```

I try to login like `ssh root@node2` from node1...but I keep get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

EDIT:

also changed permitrootlogin to this:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

did a -v on ssh and here is what I see

```
    [root@ip-10-205-119-236 .ssh]# ssh -v root@10.205.117.61
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.205.117.61 [10.205.117.61] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.205.117.61' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I see its trying to use id_dsa...but I don't have that file...i have a file called `node1` which is what I named my file...

Comment: what does the server log say? What is your `PermitRootLogin` option?

Comment: missed that one...made an edit to show it but it says `without-password`

Comment: ^^ the first question? Do you have correct acl on `.ssh` directory  and `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: no, I haven't made any acl changes to the authorized_keys file...what should I make it?

Comment: just did a `chmod 777` on that file and still got the same result...also made another edit and it seems to look for `id_dsa` but I think it should be looking for `node1`

Comment: that is not what you should do ... and if your keys is called somehow else than `id_rsa` then you need to tell `ssh` where it will find it.

Answer (score 0):

SSH requires quite precise access rights on these files because if it would be different, it is security issue. You need your `~/.ssh` to have accessible only by you and your `authorized_keys` can't be writeable by other:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

should fix it.